# Javascript make variable equal itself plus its self

Tags: javascript

I have a varible that I want to equal itself, plus itself. What is the proper syntax for this?

```
var myVar = 1;
myVar =+ myVar;
```

Comment: `var myVar = 1; myVar += myVar;` It's `+=`, the other way around ;)

Comment: `myvar += myvar` or `myvar = myvar + myvar` or `myvar *= 2` or `myvar = myvar * 2`

Comment: "Equal itself + itself" translates pretty directly to code, not sure what the issue was here. Voting to close as typo / no-repro.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks BLEX!

```
var myVar = 1; myVar += myVar;
```

Answer (score 2):

The most straight forward would be to calculate the value and assign it:

```
myVar = myVar + myVar;
```

What you are trying to do is using the `+=` operator:

```
myVar += myVar;
```

However, if I found that in code, the first though would be that it was a mistake. It's not a very intuitive way to double a value, a way that more clearly shows the intent would be to multiply by two:

```
myVar *= 2;
```

Comment: Wut? How can you do it when just defining myVar? It doesn't even exist this time, and you are already summing them and multiplying...

Comment: @nicael: Yes, the `var` was a mistake that I copied from the question.

Comment: (still, you should push some value in this var before multiplying)

Comment: @nicael: The OP has naturally alredy put a value in the variable. Otherwise the question would be totally pointless.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.